# Teradata Vmware Player connection can not be established from remote windows

Tags: teradata, vmware

I am running Teradata Express 14 running on a vmware on Ubuntu.

The versions installed:

- TDExpress14.10_Sles11_40GB
- VMware-player-14.0.0-6661328

I am able to connect to Teradata using Teradata Studio Express inside the vmware player. But i am not able to connect to Teradata from a remote windows client using Teradata Studio Express.

How can i configure network connections?

Comment: Check your VM network settings, *bridged mode* will be the easiest: check the VM's IP address using `ifconfig` and use this to logon.

Comment: I configured as bridged mode. But nothing has changed. Host machine Ubuntu has 10.20.40.40 IP adress and vmware player has 192.168.198.128 IP adress when using ifconfig. I also looked at the /etc/resolv.in file and there is a namespace 153.64.251.200

Comment: Try `ifdown eth0` followed by `ifup eth0` to refresh the VM's ip-address